# Is it possible to startup/shutdown the VM without launching IE interface?

Tags: windows-7, vmware

I am trying to get rid of the IE interface, when performing simple actions with VMware (such as starting a VM, shutting it down etc). Is it possible to write some `bat` files that will call the proper utilities to make it happen? If yes, then how?

Thanks

**Update:** Probably the following dialog will tell more info about the installed software
[image]

Comment: Oh, btw. you might want to add the `vmrun` command you're trying and which errors you receive, etc.

Comment: Still playing with that. `vmrun` has `--help` option.

Comment: ...but there are a lot of terms that I don't understand (yet): `vm with server`, `vm with workstation`, `as a guest` etc etc. A bit pity that as a customer I need to administer it so deeply.

Comment: Which version of VMWare?

Comment: @Linker3000: kindly see an update - does it help, please?